# In sql Server number of connections are instance specific or database specific

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Kindly let me know in sql Server number of connections are instance specific or database specific ?**

Comment: Of course instance specific.

Answer (score 0):

Instance specific.

`sp_configure` displays or changes global configuration settings for the current server, and 
`user connections` is one of the options.